# What model iPad do I have with this serial number dmpjj7ebf191

Tags: ipad

What generation ipad is this serial number dmpjj7ebf191

Comment: You can identify your model using Apple's instructions here: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201471

Answer (score 1):

According to a lookup tool IMEI.info your device is an

> iPad (4th generation) Wi-Fi + Cellular (MM)

See: https://www.imei.info/apple-sn-check/?sn=dmpjj7ebf191. Note that it is not an officially endorsed website.

Comment: You can also do this through Apple's offical site here: https://checkcoverage.apple.com (FYI: I get the same result).

Comment: @pdd TIL! That's a way better answer than an unofficial tool. :)